# Where are all the original users?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking through user lists, and there are tons and tons of users who posted in the first couple of months who then immediately dropped off the site completely. What happened and is it possible to get them back? Semaphore is a notable absence, since he was a moderator pro tempore (and left after someone asked for a link to a translation?) and still ranks in the top 10.

In fact, of the top 10, five haven't asked a question or given an answer since at least October (with a few going back to July or even May). I can't see comments or votes, so it's difficult to tell activity, but those aren't great number regardless.

Comment: Haven't talked to Semaphore lately, but he still is a moderator and his last activity on the site isn't that long ago (comments & edits on 1 Jan).

Comment: As I mentioned, I can't see a users comments or votes from their profile, so I wasn't aware how recent it has been. That's good that he's still around. But what of others? Just quietly voting & commenting? I suppose that's good if that's what's being done, but my question is rather is that what's being done?

Comment: Votes are not public, but almost every other activity is. You just need to switch to the activity tab in a user's profile. Here's mine: http://mythology.stackexchange.com/users/57/yannis?tab=activity That said, I'm also curious about why some of our early users went silent. When I took an almost 3 month long break from the site (sep-nov) it was because work was hectic. Hopefully, at least some of our inactive users will eventualy return.

Comment: Thanks. Been here too long to not have realized that.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly the question asked, but you can see the rest of a person's activity in the "Activity" tab on their profile page:

[image]

Clicking all actions there will allow you to view their comments, edits, suggested edits, review queue activity, etc. (No voting history, even moderators only have very limited access to voting history, as I understand it)  This reveals that, while Semaphore may not have posted a Q or A in the past couple months, he is around editing and commenting here and there.

---

Suppose I should answer the actual question though:

As far as why a lot of people left, I think [durron597's answer here](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287/what-can-we-do-to-help-mythology-stack-exchange-grow) has decent support as far as reasons.

I can only speak for myself:  Activity got low, felt like a small number of contributors were trying to shore up the sides just to serve their own vanity (myself included), also tedious topicality/quality debates, sometimes on posts that didn't seem to warrant them at all (and my dentist telling me I needed to stop grinding my teeth).

Comment: Yeah, mods can see what percentage of a user's votes were given to other users, and how many votes they recieved from other users, but only Stack Exchange employees (e.g. CMs) can see specifics.